Seeking Insights for ARIMAX Improvement
This is essentially a follow-up to my previous post
The time series I am working with exhibits both weekly and yearly seasonality, as well as a trend. I was initially using SARIMA, but it yielded poor results. I then realized that SARIMA does not handle multiple seasonalities well, so I switched to ARIMAX. The results are now decent



I used an optimized routine to find the best parameters, and the order below resulted in the lowest AIC: (14, 1, 10)
Some questions:

Although I didn't include dummy variables for the day of the week as exogenous variables, the ARIMA model seems to have "learned" this pattern. How is this possible?
If I'm not mistaken, when p and q have very high values like the ones I'm using, ARIMA should not be used. Is this correct?
This model is doing a decent job. Fridays are the peak day of the week, and both the highest and lowest forecasted points are actually holidays that have the highest and lowest sales for the forecasted period. I'm happy with the result but certainly have room for improvement. Any ideas on how to do this? I'm unsure what to try next.

